# Deep, generic serialization of ActionScript objects

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Is there any way, without having the creator of the object implement any special functions (no specific serialization functions) (however, they can use annotations), to have Flash serialize a generic, possibly deep (objects within objects within objects, etc, etc, etc) object?

If this makes no sense, comment as such and I'll try to elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) can be used for serialization of complex objects. Here's some good info:

http://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/the-abcs-of-amf-format/

Comment: It's said that this will work with anything *except* displayObjects - is there any way around that, or would each displayObject have to be extended with its own cloning methods?

Answer (score 1):

There is a generic way to clone an object - however not a deep copy though:

```
public function clone():MyObject
{
  var byteArr:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
  byteArr.writeObject(this);
  byteArr.position = 0;
  return(byteArr.readObject());
}
```

Anyway a real deep copy is sometimes not really useful as there will often be a certain level, where you will want to stop. So in general I recommend to create an ICloneable interface that defines a clone method. Implement this object for all the objects you want to have cloned and call it recursively for all instances that implement this interface.

Comment: The .writeObject()/.readObject() approach can be pretty flexible. Beyond the builtin types, you can use it to clone custom classes by first registering those classes with flash.net.registerClassAlias(). You can either let Flash do its thing, or you can have your class implement flash.utils.IExternalizable, which defines two methods, public function writeExternal( output:IDataOutput ):void and public function readExternal( input:IDataInput ):void, which let you customize exactly how an instance of that class gets serialized.

Comment: This is how I'd normally go about this - but there are a number of custom components that I'll need to be able to look at, and unfortunately it can't be a constraint that they implement their own clone methods.  (that's the only reason this problem is hard, I cannot use the memento design pattern or anything close, it has to be completely generic :( )...

Comment: well, AMF was designed with reduction of sending redundant data in mind. It works by sending only references to objects previously sent. Context creation is done transparently. Sending deep copies is simply against that. Refer https://www.slideshare.net/tomhensel/introduction-to-amf for broader info